# UIAlertController dismiss completion never gets called

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

In the following code, when my web view fails to load, the alert is properly shown with the Retry button, as expected.  The alert goes away when tapping the Retry button, but the completion never gets called.  Why is this?

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Network Error", message: "There was a error loading the page.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.webView.loadHTMLString("Reloaded", baseURL: nil)
        })
    }));

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't call `alert.dismiss` inside the alert action. The alert controller will automatically be dismissed when the user taps one of the alert buttons.

You just need:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { _ in
    self.webView.loadHTMLString("Reloaded", baseURL: nil)
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was kind of a silly mistake on my part. 

Answer (score 0):

Just  try  it out I didn't  checked ,
Change UIAlertActionStyle .default to .Cancel. Remove  dismiss block give  web  view  loading directly in  handler..
Hope  maybe  it will  help  you...

Comment: How does changing the style of the button have any bearing on the issue?